# Syntax error in for loop when redirecting output to file in background

Tags: bash, scripts, redirect

I am trying to parse some log files using a script, and since all of them can be parsed independently, I am trying to run them in the background.
I am using the following command but I get the syntax error stated right after:

```
for k in {2..3}; do for i in {1..3}; do for j in {1..3}; do ./run_parser.sh ${k} ${i} ${j} > parse_${k}${i}${j}.log 2>&1 &; done; done; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Although if I run the `run_parser.sh` script individually one by one without the loop, it runs fine. Something like:

```
./run_parser.sh 2 1 2 > parse_212.log 2>&1 &
```

works perfectly fine.

Also, I previously tried :

```
for k in {2..3}; do for i in {1..3}; do for j in {1..3}; do ./run_parser.sh ${k} ${i} ${j} & > parse_${k}${i}${j}.log ; done; done; done
```

which also worked but output redirection was not working and everything was being printed to screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should place the background command in `()` like this:

```
for k in {2..3}; do for i in {1..3}; do for j in {1..3}; do (./run_parser.sh ${k} ${i} ${j} > parse_${k}${i}${j}.log 2>&1 &); done; done; done
```

Comment: This spawn an additional but rather pointless sub-shell for every inner loop execution.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a `;` after a `&`, the `&` itself acts as a command separator. See the "List of commands" section in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) .

This will execute three concurrent `ping`:

```
ping -c 3 askubuntu.com & ping -c 3 askubuntu.com & ping -c 3 askubuntu.com &
```

Comment: This works too.

Comment: No, that's the other one (adding parentheses to compensate for a semicolon that shouldn't be there in the first place) that "works too". :)